# How did Daenerys know about the "Hand of the King" pin?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the season finale of season 6 of Game of Thrones

> Daenerys presents Tyrion with a "Hand of the Queen" pin.

She says something along the lines of "I hope I got the details right."

It is unlikely that she asked Tyrion himself about it as he seems surprised to be receiving it. It is possible that she asked Jorah about it but we don't really see them alone and they likely have not spoken off screen since maybe half way through season 5. Even if she did ask him about it, it seems unlikely that Jorah would have ever even seen the "Hand of the King" pin.

So my question is, how did Daenerys know what the "Hand of the King" pin looked like? Both the Westerosi Hand of the King pin and the Hand of the Queen pin that Daenerys gives to Tyrion look very similar considering that Daenerys has never spent a day of her adult life in Westeros.

[image: Westerosi Hand-of-the-King Pin]

[image: Tyrion's Hand-of-the-Queen Pin]

Are we supposed to believe that she asked Varys before he left?

Comment: I don't see any reason to think she would need to see it in person, or have resided in Westeros, to know what it looks like. Pentos is not far from King's Landing - there were surely books on Westerosi history in the house of Illyrio Mopatis. As the heirs deposed from their throne, it's reasonable to think that Daenerys and Viserys were interested in the kingdom they'd lost...

Comment: (In other words, I think the real question here is: Is the design of the pin well-known enough to appear in books about Westeros?)

Comment: The hand of Kingpin?? ;)

Comment: If nothing else, I would imagine that there are drawings of the pin in numerous books about Westeros. After all, the Hand of the King has been a court position for over a thousand years.

Comment: @Omegacron Actually, it's a position created by Aegon Targaryen when he conquered the Seven Kingdoms, so it's only 300 years old. But even then it shouldn't be hard to find some information in books.

Comment: I don't think it's that unlikely that Jorah has ever seen the pin. He has met the King at least once during the Greyjoy rebellion and the tourney in Lannisport afterwards, Jon Arryn could have been present at that moment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Books

First of all, this is a show only event. It has never happened in the books as Books ended when the Dothraki found Daenerys. Later, in absence of the Queen, Ser Barristan Selmy assumed the office of Hand of the King to govern the realm. From *ADWD, Chapter 59*:

> Though **he had assumed the title of Hand, Ser Barristan would not
> presume to hold court in the queen's absence**, nor would he permit
> Skahaz mo Kandaq to do such.

However since you have added the books tag, Books do refer to how she got her knowledge of Westeros. From *AGOT, Chapter 46:*

> My mother died giving me birth, and my father and my brother Rhaegar
> even before that. **I would never have known so much as their names if
> Viserys had not been there to tell me**. He was the only one left. The
> only one. He is all I have

Also from *AGOT Daenerys VI*:

> **She had never seen the Seven Kingdoms either, no more than Drogo, yet she felt as though she knew them from all the tales her brother
> had told her**. Viserys had promised her a thousand times that he
> would take her back one day, but he was dead now and his promises had
> died with him.

Viserys had even told her about the Tourneys. From *ADWD Daenerys V*:

> "One would be enough if he were as true as you." The day might come
> soon when she would have need of every knight. "Will they joust for
> me? I should like that." **Viserys had told her stories of the
> tourneys he had witnessed in the Seven Kingdoms, but Dany had never
> seen a joust herself**.

Also from *AGOT, Daenerys I*:

> **Yet sometimes Dany would picture the way it had been, so often had her brother told her the stories**. The midnight flight to
> Dragonstone, moonlight shimmering on the ship's black sails.

Viserys also told her about the Targaryen custom of incest. From *AGOT, Daenerys I:*

> She had always assumed that she would wed Viserys when she came of
> age. For centuries the Targaryens had married brother to sister, since
> Aegon the Conqueror had taken his sisters to bride. **The line must be
> kept pure, Viserys had told her a thousand times; theirs was the
> kingsblood, the golden blood of old Valyria, the blood of the
> dragon**.

He also told her about History of House Targaryen's dragons. From *AGOT, Daenerys III:*

> **Viserys had told her that the last Targaryen dragons had died no more than a century and a half ago**, during the reign of Aegon III,
> who was called the Dragonbane.

Also from *ADWD, Daenerys II*, he told her about the Dance of the Dragons:

> **Viserys had told her all the tales when she was little**. He loved to talk of dragons. She knew how Harrenhal had fallen. She knew about
> the Field of Fire and the Dance of the Dragons. One of her forebears,
> the third Aegon, had seen his own mother devoured by his uncle's
> dragon. And there were songs beyond count of villages and kingdoms
> that lived in dread of dragons till some brave dragonslayer rescued
> them.

It was also Viserys, whose knowledge had saved Daenerys' dragons from starvation in *ACOK, Daenerys I*:

> Or rather, tried to feed them, for the dragons would not eat. They
> would hiss and spit at each bloody morsel of horsemeat, steam rising
> from their nostrils, yet **they would not take the food . . . until
> Dany recalled something Viserys had told her when they were
> children**.
>
> Only dragons and men eat cooked meat, he had said.

He also told her about the Throne room and Dragon skulls that adorned the walls. From *ASOS, Daenerys I:*

> "**Viserys talked of those skulls**," said Dany. "The Usurper took
> them down and hid them away. He could not bear them looking down on
> him upon his stolen throne."

He also told her about Tragedy of Summerhall. From *ASOS, Daenerys V*:

> **Viserys had spoken of Rhaegar's birth only once**. Perhaps the tale saddened him too much. "It was the shadow of Summerhall that haunted
> him, was it not?"

He also told her about theology and faith. From *ASOS, Daenerys VI:*

> Westeros had seven gods at least, though **Viserys had told her that
> some septons said the seven were only aspects of a single god**, seven
> facets of a single crystal.

So here we see, Daenerys knows all she knows thanks to Viserys. To sum it up, following are the subjects Viserys told her about:

1. Her self, Her rights and Her House
2. The tales of Seven Kingdoms
3. Customs and culture of Seven Kingdoms
4. History of House Targaryen
5. Some mysteries of Dragonlore
6. History of Dragons
7. Faith of the Seven Kingdoms

So if this event does happen in the books, It would most likely be Viserys who would have told her about the pin and the office of Hand of the King.

---

## Show

There is no indication in the show that who told her about the office and its pin.

The exact dialogue in S06E10 was:

> Daenerys: I, um... **I had something made for you. I'm not sure if
> it's right**. Tyrion Lannister, I name you Hand of the Queen.

Since she wasn't sure about the exact appearance having never seen the pin personally but yet had it made, that implies she did so with help of verbal description she may have heard from someone. Following are the candidates who may have told her about the pin custom:

1. Viserys Targaryen
2. Jorah Mormont
3. Barristan Selmy
4. Tyrion Lannister

The most plausible one of them is Viserys since he was the one who told Daenerys everything she knew.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. This definitely answered my question. But I don't think it was necessary to put all this evidence in to show that Viserys taught Dany about Westeros.

Answer (score 4):

> "I am Daenerys Stormborn of the House Targaryen, of the blood of Old
>   Valyria. **Valyrian is my mother tongue**."

With her brother, Dænerys had a classical education under [Sir Willem Darry](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Willem_Darry) and other Targaryen loyalists at the House of the Red Door, preparing her for a future position as trueborn Westerosi royalty (as part of the Dornish conspiracy to retake the Iron Throne).

Furthermore, after the events involving Viserys and Drogo, she started seeing herself as the rightful heir to the Throne, and given her personality, we can safely assume she would prepare herself as well as she could—in many scenes, we see she's eager to learn everything she can from Barristan and others. There's all the reasons to suppose she must be familiar with Westerosi court protocol, heraldry and symbolism—and have the motivation to ask her advisers about whatever's lacking from books.

Recall, for example, that the Hand of the King tradition was started by her great ancestor, Aegon I Targaryen.

Comment: Actually Daenerys never lived in the house with red door for long. She was a child when Ser Willem Darry died and their servants forced the targ siblings out. Her only source for getting info was her brother

Comment: Oh and as for speaking Valyrian, She grew up in Free cities where people speak dialects of Valyrian in their day to day lives along with High Valyrian. So, while impressive, it isn't strange that she speaks High Valyrian. I don't think there was any training given to her for it which is further reinforced given the brief time she spent in Bravos with Ser Willem Darry.

Comment: Not to mention, there is no indication that Targaryens kept speaking Valyrian as their mother tongue after Aegon's death

Comment: I think you're  right about Viserys being her main source of information about Westeros. But High Valyrian is a classical language (an explicit analogue to Latin), not a vernacular (the Low speeches of Essos are like Italian, Spanish etc.) At the time of the show, the only way to learn proper High is through deliberate instruction (like Latin in the middle ages), which is why her comment of "mother language" is a boast. And mother tongues are acquired between zero and five years.

Comment: I understand that and how High Valyrian equates to Latin irl, However, I take issue with that because she could not have learnt it from her mother as  she died giving birth to her, Willem Darry was a Riverlander and therefore couldn't speak Valyrian, They had servants but no indication is there that they hired a servant to teach the kids Valyrian, It implies that Royal Family kept speaking High Valyrian after 3 centuries as their mother tongue which is unlikely given they assimilated into locals by adopting their culture, religion etc and only retaining incest from their own culture.

Comment: (cont.) Who did educate Viserys on his birthright, on Westerosi history etc.? The same people must have thought of High as a mark of distinction and as the language of royals. They must have immersed the refugee couple into it, as preparation for the deal with the Martell. This is what I meant by "a classical education"—the kind a peasant wouldn't have. Thought you're right, the timeline is such that Dæny must have learned most things second-hand from her brother.

Comment: Viserys was 8 YO or older when Targaryens were overthrown IIRC. So he was already under training as befit the second in line to the Iron Throne (Given how nobles start early e.g. Bran was the same age and knew a lot about Stark heritage and history of Westeros). Viserys wasn't always correct in his memories as Barristan Selmy told Daenerys later. But that is understandable since Rhaella kept Viserys away from Aerys as much as she could. So IMO Viserys' knowledge comes from KL, rather than from Bravos.